# Using last column's value in tabular form in apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm new to Oracle APEX.I have a master/detail form and in the detail, which is a tabular, I need to pass the values of last column.
Let me clearyfy : Say we have 3 columns,all use LOVs.In the first one we pick the first name,in the second one we want to pick the last name, but the LOV must show us just the family names related to the first name returned by LOV,and the third one must show just the orders from that person (based on name and falmiy).
The guy who taught me the basics said it is impossible,but I still believe there must be a way.We use Apex 4.2 .
Thank in advance.

PS : It will help like 20-25 people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need a Cascading LOV just like Chris Story said, the problem is that there's no cascading option in a tabular forms so you'll need to do some work...

[Check out Jari Lane guide to accomplish that.](http://dbswh.webhop.net/htmldb/f?p=BLOG%3aREAD:0%3a%3a%3a%3aARTICLE:2003800346210117)

Comment: That's exactly the point,no cascade LOV in tabular.
Thanks for the link,I'll try it ASAP.

Comment: It looks like the thing we need!

Answer (score 0):

APEX has this functionality built-in.  The capability is called Cascading LOVs and is an option setting when creating a LOV.

Typically, the premise is that when the first LOV is set, it triggers the second LOV with a SQL query which has the value from the first LOV embedded in the query.  Same thing for the third one.  Keyword that will help you in searching documentation is CASCADING LOV.  Hope that helps.

Comment: That's not true when talking about tabular forms though; which is what OP is saying.